# working with date in php

Tags: php

Hello i am doing web for statistic. There is problem in time span. There is two input from and to.
[image: time span]

they are by default and takes time from following code:

```
$date = date('y-m-d');
$sd = strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$trgD = date ( 'y-m-d' , $sd );
```

than i printing them to the two inputs (from and to). Now i have a problem when user enter the time. how can i store them to    $date and $trgD;
What should i do?
the form code is:

```
<form name="sdate" method="post" action="index.php">
      <td width="38" height="35">Аас</td>
      <td width="89">
      <input name="date1" id="date1" title="Эхлэх өдөр" size="14" value="<?php echo     $trgD ?>" type="text">


      </td>
      <td width="48"><input style="padding-bottom: 4px;" src="images/img1.gif" alt="Та өдрөө сонгоно уу" title="эхлэх өдөр сонгох" onClick="return showCalendar('date1');" align="absmiddle" border="0" type="image"></td>
      <td width="61">Хүртэл </td>
      <td width="97"><input name="date2" id="date2" title="Дуусах өдөр" size="14" value="<?php echo $date ?>" type="text"></td>
      <td width="77"><input style="padding-bottom: 4px;" src="images/img1.gif" alt="Дуусах өдрийг сонгох" title="Дуусах өдөр" onClick="return showCalendar('date2');" align="absmiddle" border="0" type="image"></td>
      <td width="196">
   <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Илгээх"> 
      </td>
      </form>
```

i need to set condition like:

```
if (user submit){
$date=store submited date1;
$trgD= store submited date2;}

else{ 
$date = date('y-m-d');
$sd = strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$trgD = date ( 'y-m-d' , $sd ); }
```

i do not know how to write this condition

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the dates or you are trying to store the values into variables?

Comment: i want to store date instead of default date when user enter date

Comment: You want to insert / store them into database?

Comment: now i have explained more better in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, storing submitted dates into variables is fairly easy.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['trgD'])) 
       { $trgD = date ( 'y-m-d' , $sd );} 

    else if(empty($_POST['date2'])) 
       { $date2 = date('y-m-d'); }

    }else {
        $sd = strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
        $trgD = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trgD ']);
        $date2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);



        <form name="sdate" method="post" action="index.php">
              <td width="38" height="35">Аас</td>
              <td width="89">
              <input name="date1" id="date1" title="Эхлэх өдөр" size="14" value="<?php echo     $trgD ?>" type="text">


              </td>
              <td width="48"><input style="padding-bottom: 4px;" src="images/img1.gif" alt="Та өдрөө сонгоно уу" title="эхлэх өдөр сонгох" onClick="return showCalendar('date1');" align="absmiddle" border="0" type="image"></td>
              <td width="61">Хүртэл </td>
              <td width="97"><input name="date2" id="date2" title="Дуусах өдөр" size="14" value="<?php echo $date ?>" type="text"></td>
              <td width="77"><input style="padding-bottom: 4px;" src="images/img1.gif" alt="Дуусах өдрийг сонгох" title="Дуусах өдөр" onClick="return showCalendar('date2');" align="absmiddle" border="0" type="image"></td>
              <td width="196">
           <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Илгээх"> 
              </td>
              </form>


        }}
```

Comment: can i do this with condition? i mean if user submit dates it will saves in $date and $trdD else it will take default date

Comment: It depends on what you want, if the user does not submit the data? What do you want to appear? Zero? Or do you want to force the user to fill anything?

Comment: if user not submit it take date by this code $date = date('y-m-d');
$sd = strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$trgD = date ( 'y-m-d' , $sd );

Comment: today and a month ago. i want to know how to set condition? am i explain my question clear?

Comment: You can try the above code, that is from my understanding if user did not fill date2 and trgD, then set a value

Comment: thanks for answer now i have picture in it. it was very helpful for me thanks

Comment: No problem. If you have more question, you can ask me